# How to toggle between two texts using css

Tags: html, css

I have two language selector on the top right corner of the screen like EN | FR. When the user clicks the EN the color and text decoration of the EN text should get changed.When the useer clicks on the FR the text decoration and color and also the EN should get back to its original color and text decoration.The functions should toggle.

Is there any way to achive it using HTML and CSS only?

Comment: default EN/FR color is same or different?

Comment: default color for both are same

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo-class over the elements containing `EN`/`FR`. In this case, elements should have the ability to receive focus. A possible solution is to give that elements a `tabindex` attribute:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: gold;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:focus {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span tabindex="-1">EN</span>
<span tabindex="-1">FR</span>
```

Note that `:focus` is applied as long as the user doesn't click on elsewhere on the page.

Also it's worth noting that `:focus` is well supported in legacy web browsers.

---

Another option is to use radio button hack with [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo-class to toggle the styles:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: gold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[id^="lang_"] {
  display: none;
}

input[id^="lang_"]:checked + label {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="lang_en" name="language">
<label for="lang_en">EN</label>

<input type="radio" id="lang_fr" name="language">
<label for="lang_fr">FR</label>
```

`:checked` pseudo-class is supported in IE9+.

Comment: That only works as long as the user does nothing else with the page.  As soon as they click on something else, the focus is lost.

Comment: @JohnFisher That's right. Just added an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

If clicking EN or FR actually loads a new page, then you can do this with only CSS and HTML.  You would specify `class="en"` or `class="fr"` in the appropriate HTML location.  Then the CSS can easily apply at the right times.

However, if you are not loading a new page when the user clicks those items, you will need JavaScript.  It could change the class for you, and the same CSS could work.